# How to remove files expect first and last file by modification date per day in a folder with bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

As the title say. I have a folder with huge amount of files. I need to be able to remove every file expect the first and last file by modification date per each day. How can I do this with a bash shell script?

This is how I can remove everything expect the first file per modification time, but how to reserve also the last?

```
  find /mnt/backups/ -name "db_backup*" -mtime +7 -printf '%TD %TT %p\0' |
  sort -z |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' line
  do
    currentdate=${line%% *}
    if [ "$currentdate" = "$prevdate" ]
    then
      filepath=$(cut -d ' ' -f3- <<< $line)
      rm -- "$filepath"
    fi
    prevdate=$currentdate
  done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Are you using the time (the `%TT` field in the printf format) anywhere? If not, why keep it?

Answer (score 0):

`perl` not-so-one-liner that does what it sounds like you want - groups all files by day of last modification, and then sorts each day's files to get all but the first and last ones of each day.

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -E '
  for (glob "*.txt") { # Adjust pattern as needed
    my $mtime = (stat)[9];
    push @{$files{strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime $mtime)}}, [ $_, $mtime ]
  }
  for (values %files) {
    my @files = map { $_->[0] } sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @$_;
    if (@files > 2) { say for @files[1..$#files-1] }
  }'
```

Once you test it and verify that it prints out just the files you want to delete, replace the `say for` with `unlink` to actually delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but should be plain bash shell script :).

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code is really close to what you need. Consider storing the last line the same way you store the last date.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

root=/mnt/backups # to make it easier for folks to test
prevpath=
while IFS= read -r -d ' ' currdate && IFS= read -r -d '' filepath; do
  if [ "$currdate" = "$prevdate" ]; then
    [[ $prevpath ]] && rm -- "$prevpath"
    prevpath=$filepath
  else
    [[ $prevpath ]] && {
      : "Not deleting: $prevpath"  # for xtrace logging
      prevpath=
    }
  fi
  prevdate=$currdate
done < <(find "$root" -mtime +7 -printf '%TD %p\0' | sort -z)
[[ $prevpath ]] && : "Not deleting: $prevpath" >&2
```

If you run `bash -x thisscript`, you'll see "Not deleted" logged for the various files being skipped. (Using `< <(...)` instead of piping into the loop ensures that variables are preserved, so we can log the file we aren't deleting at the very end of execution).